# How can I press the iPhone Home button using PC keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iphone, usb-keyboard

I have:
- a iPhone with a (mostly) broken screen (no touch capability)
- a PC keyboard (USB)
- a lightning-to-USB cable
- a female-to-female USB adapter

The keyboard is plugged into the female-to-female USB adapter that is plugged into the lightning-to-USB cable that is plugged into the iPhone.

Is there a key combination to press on the PC keyboard to swipe the locked screen?

Comment: According to the comments here, hit Caps Lock twice: http://lifehacker.com/quickly-unlock-your-ipad-using-just-an-external-keyboar-1207624915

Comment: That's using an already-paired bluetooth keyboard.  You cannot simply connect a USB keyboard to an iPhone - it will not recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

CapsLock twice will only work once a keyboard is actually connected & recognised. Over Bluetooth - the only way to add a keyboard without additional hardware - you would first need to pair them, which would require you can actually use the phone as intended.

An iPhone natively cannot detect a USB keyboard. 
The only way to connect a USB keyboard to an iPhone is using the [Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter).

I'm still not certain it will then wake the phone. Even if it does, you still require a functional touchscreen to launch an app.

So, TL:DR - get the screen fixed.